# userName/password Identity on OPC UA Server?

Tags: node.js, authentication, server, client-server, node-opcua

In Client:

```
let  userIdentity = { userName: "user1", password: "user1" };
session = await client.createSession(userIdentity);
```

In Server

```
var userManager = {

isValidUser: function (userName, password) {

    if (userName === "user1" && password === "password1") {

        return true;
    }

    if (userName === "user2" && password === "password2") {
        return true;
    }

    return false;}};
```

When Clients create session with OPCUA Server, it will send userName/password Identity to activeSession on Server. How to I can know that userName when client connect to Server on my Server?

Comment: Please update your question/code sample, to make it more understandable!

Answer (score 1):

You have to register the user manager on your server. See [example](https://github.com/node-opcua/node-opcua/issues/319)

```
var server_options = {
...
userManager: userManager,

allowAnonymous: false,
};

var server = new OPCUAServer(server_options);
```

Then you your callback will be called

Comment: no, I added this code in my Server. My problem is I need show userName that is used to connect to My server?

Comment: can you support me about callback to do this?

Comment: I tried ```console.log(userName)``` behind ```return true``` but not effective

Comment: You mean: "I tried console.log(userName) BEFORE return true but not effective."

Comment: ex: ```if (userName === "user1" && password === "password1") {
           
console.log(userName)
           return true; ```
    }